# Why is it necessary to specify Angular modules with factory functions, instead of similar how I specify Node modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, node-modules, angularjs-module

I've recently begun using angularjs. But it's concept of modules confuses me.

In one of the angular tutorials, there's the following code:

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

var phonecatServices = angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']);

//this line's added by me
phonecatServices.constant('SomeConstant', 123);

phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

Why does angularjs require helper functions like constant or factory, when it can just as well define modules in a manner similar to that of nodejs which is much cleaner? I'm confused as to what advantages this approach has.

```
var $resource = require('$resource');

var SomeConstant = 123;

var Phone = $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
    });
};

exports.SomeConstant = SomeConstant;
exports.Phone = Phone;
```

Comment: Angular modules are not really AMD modules they are part of internal angular framework definition to define module but the second one you mentioned in CommonJS syntax to define modules which is generally used on server side like Node.js

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems centered around angular's dependency injection.

Consider `angular.module` to be as the [api](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module) says, a global means to create/register or retrieve your module.  A module needs to be created in this way so the [`$injector`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.injector), which is a function that takes a list of module names that have been registered, can find it at the time of [bootstrapping](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap).

I wouldn't consider the `factory` function a 'helper', but instead actually a way of specifying to angular js's dependency injection how a service is supposed to be created.  Or as the [dependency injection guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) puts it -- we are 'teaching' the $injector how to create a service:

```
// Provide the wiring information in a module
angular.module('myModule', []).

  // Teach the injector how to build a 'greeter'
  // Notice that greeter itself is dependent on '$window'
  factory('greeter', function($window) {
    // This is a factory function, and is responsible for 
    // creating the 'greet' service.
    return {
      greet: function(text) {
        $window.alert(text);
      }
    };
  });

// New injector is created from the module. 
// (This is usually done automatically by angular bootstrap)
var injector = angular.injector(['myModule', 'ng']);

// Request any dependency from the injector
var greeter = injector.get('greeter');
```

The guide also reminds us that here, the injector is created directly from a module, but usually angular's bootstrapper takes care of that for us.

So, in short, **`angular.module` tells angular how to resolve modules (which it does via `$injector`), and `factory` tells angular how to make or them when they're needed. In contrast, Node's modules have a one-to-one mapping with files and are resolved and made in [this way](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).**